# Wimshurst machine construction

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics

I'm building a [Wimshurst Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimshurst_machine), but I cannot find acrylic used for the discs. My understanding is that the discs and metal sectors need to be insulated from each other.

Will vynil discs work?

As far as I can tell the "vynil" plastic is non-conductive, or at least as conductive as acrylic and it should be rigid enough to withstand the spinning motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most glass shops deal in sheet-acrylic (plexiglas, perspex, etc.)  Some of them have a scraps bin, where you'll sometimes find meter-wide cutoff sheets.  Call around.

Vinyl works fine, but avoid newer vinyl record albums.  Since the ? late 1970s? record albums contain anti-static materials to prevent contact-charging and dust-attraction, and are very slightly conductive.  The conductivity is more than enough to prevent Wimshurst operation.

Classic conductivity test: in a low-humidity environment rub your sample surface upon wool or, better, fur, and see if it becomes charged and visibly attracts the wool/fur fibers.  If so, then it's probably a good enough insulator for use in electrostatic generators.

Comment: Thank you! I tested the discs I was planning to use and they appear to have the anti-static property you mentioned (they're from the 90s). I guess I will have to look around a bit more and see if I can find some acrylic. Again, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Middlesticks first verify that humidity is low enough:  rub your arm-hair on some styrofoam, or an inflated balloon, or inflated plastic bag.   If your hair doesn't respond, then it won't respond to "good" plastics either.   But if your rubbed hair responds to balloons etc., but the vinyl record does nothing, that means you've got a carbon-loaded conductive record.   Note that the conductivity can be hundreds or even thousands of meg-ohms, and that's enough to mess up the contact-electrification effect.  An ohmmeter might never detect such a large value.